# How to import tensor_shape in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow-cpu 2.1 on python 3.6 64-bit environment. The code I have downloaded using

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
```

to import tensor_shape, but in my environment, tensorflow.python.framework is unresolved import.

I also tried

```
from tensorflow import tensor_shape
```

, which does not work either.

Anyone knows how to import tensor_shape in tensorflow-cpu 2.1 and python 3.6? Thanks a lot.

Update: The code I downloaded used

```
tf.random_uniform(tensor_shape.scalar(), minval=1.0, maxval=resize_scale)
```

, which is why tensor_shape module is imported.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the tensor shape you just have to use the following lines(note that the function is `tf.shape` not `tensor_shape`:

```
#From official documentation
import tensorflow as tf
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
tf.shape(t)
```

Comment: Thank you but the code only calls tensor_shape.scalar(), seems tensor_shape is not used for getting the shape of a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

You can import tensor_shape using:

```
     from tensorflow_core.python.framework import tensor_shape
```